# Ignore lines in file starting with "#" sign in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, char

I'm trying to parse a text file in Java. In this text file, comments(things I don't want to parse) are denoted by a "#" sign at the beginning of the line.

I thought this would be really simple, something like:

```
String line ="#hi everyone";

if(!line.startsWith("#")){
//do stuff
}
```

But it doesn't work. I've also tried using !line.substring(0,1).equals("#"), .contains, and messed around with chars and more complicated regex stuff but with no luck.

I've watched it in the debugger and checked to make sure that the value for "line" is actually the correct value. It is correct, the line starts with #, and yet it somehow is passing the test in my if statement.

Am I missing something really basic here?

Comment: [Are you sure](http://ideone.com/PYwKS) it's not working?

Comment: You sure it a mistake!
I may be wrong but you can try line.substring(0,1) = "#"

If that fails you can make a secondary string which contains the first letter then just use the if statement on that. This should be easily found on Google, sorry I haven't coded something like this recently!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
String line ="#hi everyone";

if(!line.charAt(0) == '#'){
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, it was actually working and just messing up somewhere else! I just had my breakpoint set at the wrong place when I was debugging... sigh.

Comment: It happens. At least now you ahve 4 different ways of doing what you want to do.

Comment: @BabakNaffas Your if statement could be replaced by `if(line.charAt(0) != '#')` which is simpler

Answer (score 2):

try either of the following:

```
regex: "^[ \\t]*#.*"
```

or

```
line.trim().startsWith("#")
```